# Share session between WebViews Android WebView

Tags: android, cookies, react-native, webview

I'm using React Native to merge two native apps into a single codebase, as an intermediate app I have a WebView-based solution where we just show parts of our website inside WebViews.

On iOS, the user logs into one WebView, then all other WebViews refresh in the background and once finished loading the user will be logged in and be able to access all logged in features.

I was expecting the same behaviour on Android, however nothing happens. It's as if the user never logged in. I tried manually setting the cookies with `react-native-cookies`, however this doesn't fix the issue either.

Is it possible to have the same functionality as iOS currently has on Android?